Error when decoding OAEP filling. RSA - encryption
I need to make a cryptosystem based on the RSA cipher using RSA C# modules where:

generation of a pair of "open-closed" keys;
encryption using a public key;
decryption using a private key.

I had no problems performing the first two steps. However, when I click on the "Decrypt" button, I get an error when decrypting the OAEP fill.
Could you help me fix the the error?
using System;using System.Text;using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace RSA{

     public partial class Form1 : Form {
         private RSAParameters publicKey;
         private RSAParameters privateKey;

         public Form1()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }
    
         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             GenerateKeys();
             // Output of received keys to labels
             publicKeyLabel.Text = GetKeyString(publicKey);
             privateKeyLabel.Text = GetKeyString(privateKey);
         }
    
    
         private void GenerateKeys()
         {
             using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
             {
                 // Set the key size to 1024 bits
                 rsa.KeySize = 1024;
                 // Key pair generation
                 publicKey = rsa.ExportParameters(false); // Public key
             }
    
             using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
             {
                 rsa.KeySize = 1024;
                 // Key pair generation
                 privateKey = rsa.ExportParameters(true); // Private key
             }
         }
       
         // Method to get the string representation of the key
         static string GetKeyString(RSAParameters key)
         {
             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
             sb.AppendLine($"Module (n): {BitConverter.ToString(key.Modulus).Replace("-", "")}");
             sb.AppendLine($"Exponent (e): {BitConverter.ToString(key.Exponent).Replace("-", "")}");
             return sb.ToString();
         }
    
         // Encryption
    
         private void buttonChooseFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             string filePath = GetFilePath();
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
             {
                 string textToEncrypt = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
                 originalTextLabel.Text = $"Original text: {textToEncrypt}";
             }
         }
    
         private void buttonEncrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             string textToEncrypt = originalTextLabel.Text.Replace("Original text: ", "");
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textToEncrypt))
             {
                 string encryptedText = EncryptText(textToEncrypt, publicKey);
                 encryptedTextLabel.Text = $"Encrypted text: {encryptedText}";
             }
         }
    
         private string GetFilePath()
         {
             using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
             {
                 openFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                 if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                 {
                     return openFileDialog.FileName;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     return null;
                 }
             }
         }
    
         private string EncryptText(string text, RSAParameters publicKey)
         {
             using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
             {
                 rsa.ImportParameters(publicKey);
                 byte[] encryptedBytes = rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text), RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1);
                 return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
             }
         }
    
         private string DecryptText(string encryptedText, RSAParameters privateKey)
         {
             using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
             {
                 rsa.ImportParameters(privateKey);
                 byte[] encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
                 byte[] decryptedBytes = rsa.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA1);
                 return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes);
             }
         }
    
         private void buttonDecrypt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             string encryptedText = encryptedTextLabel.Text.Replace("Encrypted text: ", "");
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(encryptedText))
             {
                 string decryptedText = DecryptText(encryptedText, privateKey); // We use the private key for decryption
                 decryptedTextLabel.Text = $"Decrypted text: {decryptedText}";
             }
         }
     }
}


Fix the formatting. ...I get an error... what error do you get? It would be best to get rid of all the GUI code and create a [mre] to illustrate the problem. It does look like you are creating two unrelated keypairs, so note that you can only encrypt/decrypt using the matching public and private keys from a single keypair.

Yep, encrypt / decrypt with the keys from the same key pair.
